# Location of Revit DB Link log file

Tags: revit

I am searching for the Revit DB Link 2015 log file, to see the error log. Is there a log file and where is it?

I searched in the Windows Event log, and in Revit folder but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revit uses "Journal" files for error reporting.

Here's a link on finding the location of those files -
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Location-of-journal-files.html

**For 2012 and later products**:

Windows XP: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Autodesk\Revit\\Journals
Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Autodesk\Revit\\Journals

**For earlier releases (2011, 2010, 2009, 2008**):

Windows XP, Vista, or Windows 7: C:\Program Files\\Journals

Comment: please add relevant info from this link to your answer. Links may change and then the info is lost.